# What does 2-jigen or 3-jigen mean?

Tags: meaning, words, manga, culture

In conversations done among **heavily otaku** people, I often hear the words 2-jigen or 3-jigen used. I know its meaning: two-dimension and three dimension, except that it does not always seem to make sense. For example, in a conversation I found recently between two otaku people in Tokyo and Kyoto,

```
 watashi wa 4-jigen kara kimashita. dakara 3-jigen de samishiku arimasen.
```

the first sentence, I can understand literally. But in the second sentence, what does it mean? The literal translation "(not) lonely in/at 3-dimension" does not make sense to me. How can I interpret that? I only hear this use among otaku people, not ordinary people. Is this a jargon among **heavily otaku** people? I just can't grasp the meaning!

Comment: Try substituting "2D world" or "3D world".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically it's a joke. Since most otakus supposedly feel more comfortable in 2D world (anime/manga) than 3D world (reality), this guy makes a play on it and says he feels fine in 3D because he comes from a 4D world.